# SQL return Information by not existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'v got this Problem on SQLPlus:

From this code:

```
select distinct username, name, surname
from users
where username in ('user1', 'user2');
```

I get:

```
username         name           surname   
--------------- -------------- -------------
user1            Alex            Ander
```

but I need:

```
username         name           surname   
--------------- -------------- -------------
user1            Alex            Ander
user2            not exists     not exists
```

Or something like this. If an User do not Exists, the Table have to write the Username, and the rest something like "not exists" too,

Please Help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope to explain it now more clearly:

The original code what I have now is:

```
select distinct username, name, surname
from users u, accounts a
where u.user_nr = a.user_nr
and username in (
'existing_user',
'not_existing_user'
) order by username;
```

and it gives me:

```
USERNAME                  NAME            SURNAME  
------------------------- --------------- ---------------
existing_user              Hello           All

1 row selected.
```

and I need:

```
USERNAME                  NAME            SURNAME  
------------------------- --------------- ---------------
existing_user             Hello           All
not_existing_user     Not Exists      Not Exists

2 row selected.
```

The Problem: the user not_existing_user is not existing in the DataBase, 
but the query has to show him anyway from the code
with the Info - User not in the DB. 
For 500 Users I can not check everyone separate :/

Answer (score 1):

This should also work;

```
select distinct T.username, 
                coalesce(u.name, 'not exists'), 
                coalesce(u.surname, 'not exists')
from  (values ('user1'),('user2'),('user3')) as T(username)
      left join Users u on T.username = u.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  distinct username
,       coalesce(name, 'not exists')
,       coalesce(surname, 'not exists')
from    (
        select 'user1' as username
        union all
        select 'user2'
        ) list
left join
        users
on      list.username = users.username
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the list of users is not dynamic. The question author does not make it clear which is the case here.

Comment: Hmm ok, unfortunately the ISNULL() function will not work.. SqlServer functions wont work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT username,
ISNULL(Name,'Not Exists'),
ISNULL(Surname,'Not Exists')
FROM users
  WHERE (username IN ('user1','user2') OR username IS NULL)
```

Comment: By the code:

select distinct username,
isnull(name,'nothing'),
isnull(surname,'nothing')
from employers m, employers w
where m.employers_nr = w.employers_nr
and ( username in (
'user1',
'user2'
) OR username is null);

I get the error: 

ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier